# How do I access Keys/values of a nested List?

Tags: c#, prime31

I'm using a unity plugin to handle Facebook called prime[31] Social Networking Plugin. It works fine for something like this:

```
void onGraph()
    {
        Facebook.instance.graphRequest( "me", HTTPVerb.GET, ( error, obj ) =>
        {
            // if we have an error we dont proceed any further
            if( error != null )
                return;             
            if( obj == null )
                return;             
            // grab the userId and persist it for later use
            var ht = obj as Dictionary<string,object>;
            _userId = ht["id"].ToString();      

            Debug.Log( "me Graph Request finished: " + _userId );
            Prime31.Utils.logObject( ht );
        } );
    }
```

It returns this:

```
 --------- IDictionary ---------
id: ########## 
name: Mike O'Connor 
first_name: Mike 
last_name: O'Connor 
link: https://www.facebook.com/########## 
username: ########## 
etc...
```

and I can seemingly grab any key and stuff it into a variable like this, right?:

```
_userId = ht["id"].ToString();
```

but when I request the scores of everyone playing my game:?

```
void onGetScore()

    {
        Facebook.instance.graphRequest( "AppID/scores", HTTPVerb.GET, ( error, obj ) =>
        {
            // if we have an error we dont proceed any further
            if( error != null )
                return;

            if( obj == null )
                return;
            // grab the userId and persist it for later use
            var ht = obj as Dictionary<string, object>;
            _score = ht["score"].ToString();
            Prime31.Utils.logObject( ht );
        } );
    }
```

It returns a nested dictionary/list like this:

```
 --------- IDictionary --------- 

 --------- IList --------- 
data: 
    --------- IDictionary ---------
    user:    --------- IDictionary ---------
        name:   Mike O'Connor
        id:     ##########
        score:  5677
        application:     --------- IDictionary ---------
            name:   ##########
            namespace:  ##########
            id:     ##########
```

now it's nested so I can't use this, right?

```
_score = ht["score"].ToString();
```

How do I get at the nested keys? Is it just a syntax problem or do I have to recast (or something else)?

Comment: You say "the scores of everyone playing my game". Do you want the sum of all their scores, the average, the score of the first player, a list containing the score for each player, or something else?

Comment: It's for a leaderboard so I'm looking for a list that has the "name" and "score" of each user.

Comment: You can easily attach Monodevelop at runtime and put a breakpoint when these lines occur,then you can simply inspect the results you've received and see how you need to access it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to access the value of a key-value pair inside a dictionary, inside a dictionary, inside a list, inside a dictionary?

It sounds like you want this:

```
_score = ht["data"][0]["score"].ToString();
```

Note, the `0` here represents the first item in the `ht["data"]` list.

Unfortunately it looks like your objects are probably weakly typed. In that case you'd have to do:

```
_score = 
    ((IDictionary<string, object>)
        ((IList<object>)ht["data"])[0])["score"].ToString();
```

Which looks terrible, but should work (assume the types returned are really what you describe).

To get an set of user name / score pairs, you can use something like this Linq query:

```
var scores = 
    from item in ((IList<object>)ht["data"]).Cast<IDictionary<string, object>>()
    let name = ((IDictionary<string, object>)item["user"])["name"].ToString()
    let score = item["score"].ToString()
    select new { username = name, score };
```

Comment: first one doesn't work, second throws: KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Perhaps I didn't understand how you described the result object. Can you update your question to be a bit more clear?

Comment: First, thanks for working w/ me here. The result object in the original post is copied straight from the xcode debugger (minus the "###'s"). Is that what you're asking? or do you want me to clarify what I want in the end? for starters I'd just like to be able to get that score and stuff it in a variable. Ultimately I want create a list of user name/score.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor Break it down a bit more. Where execute each piece in a different statement, e.g. `var list = (IList<object>)ht["data"]; var item0 = (IDictionary<string, object>)list[0];`, etc. And tell me what part gives you the error, please.

Comment: sorry, now I understand. This is straight from the fb graph API:{
  "data": [
    {
      "user": {
        "name": " ", 
        "id": " "
      }, <br>
      "score": 0,
      "application": {
        "name": " ", 
        "namespace": " ", 
        "id": " "
      }
    },

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to change the property access logic. `ht["score"]` doesn't exist anymore (or at least isn't at the outer level, it's in a dictionary that's in a list that's in a dictionary). Instead it will be like `ht["list1"].First()["score"].ToString()` however I'm not sure what the exact path would be because your data format is not clear. Can you just update with the raw response? Then I can tell you for sure. Also, I think you'll likely have to do some iteration. Because the structure is nested more than once to get the inner values you have to iterate the outer dictionary, and then the list it contains, then access the values in the dictionaries that list contains.

Comment: as I understand it, the debug log above is raw. I changed the line "var ht = obj as Dictionary<string,object>;" to "var ht = obj;" and it returned the same thing. Is that what you're asking?

Comment: @MikeO'Connor no. I wanted to see the raw response you get from FB's API. I was saying (in particular with the text formatting) it is was difficult to read what the structure should be. It's more clear now after psgw's edit but I'd rather still read the raw data myself and go "oh that's a dictionary which contains lists and each item in the list is a dictionary." I can't provide the write expression to access data at the most inner level without know exactly what the structure is. By the way, if you just play around in the IDE it will guide you in the right direction. Think of it step by step.